# help in the using of /etc/hosts

Tags: networking, server, ssh

I am new on unix systems, I want to ask about the hosts file that is in `/etc/hosts` what does used for ?? 
also  I want to ask that when connect using ssh=> I wrote on hosts file the following
`x.x.x.x (server IP) server.hostname`

and when use `ssh root@server.hostname` it says that  `Unable to resolve host 'server.hostname': Connection failed`.

Comment: If you're looking for a convenient way to map hostnames to IP addresses *for SSH*, I'd suggest using your `~/.ssh/config` file instead

Answer (score 0):

As your machine gets started, it will need to know the mapping of some hostnames to IP addresses before DNS can be referenced. This mapping is kept in the `/etc/hosts` file.

In the absence of a name server, any network program on your system consults this file to determine the IP address that corresponds to a host name.

For your second question try to restart the network manager after editing your `/etc/hosts` file by typing this in terminal 
`sudo service network-manager restart`